# garbage collection batch job jvm arguments

Tags: garbage-collection, java-11, ibm-jdk

We have following jvm arguments while running batch jobs. These arguments are specific to ibm jdk 8. What are the corresponding variables for open jdk 8?

```
<jvmSettings>
<maxMemorySize>6144m</maxMemorySize>
<extraArguments>
<extraArgument>-D64</extraArgument>
<extraArgument>-Xgcpolicy:gencon</extraArgument>
</extraArguments>
</jvmSettings>
```

Comment: There is no need to specify any option, as generational garbage collection is the default for the HotSpot JVM. In fact, this is also the default for IBM’s JVM, so specifying this option had no effect anyway.